# 変数と変数を合わせて別の変数を読み込みたい

Tags: javascript

`tests1`と`tests2`だけを使って`CC`を出力させるにはどうすればいいですか？

```
var tests1 = "AA"
var tests2 = "BB"
var AABB = "CC"

console.log(tests1 + tests2); //AABB
```

Comment: [eval() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問は、もしかしたら [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)になっているかもしれません。なぜこのようなことをしたくなったのかを質問を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブラウザ環境であれば、次のようにすることで可能です。

```js
var tests1 = "AA"
var tests2 = "BB"
var AABB = "CC"

console.log(window[tests1 + tests2])
```

これは、ブラウザで普通のJavaScriptとしてそのまま読み込んだ場合のみうまくいきます。type="module"とモジュールとして読み込んだ場合や、Node.jsを使った場合、また、Webpack等で他のJavaScriptと結合した場合はうまくいきません。なお、`var`の代わりに`let`や`const`等を使った場合もうまくいきません。

---

以下、解説です。

ブラウザのJavaScirptのトップレベル(グローバルコンテキスト)で`var`で宣言された変数はグローバルオブジェクトのプロパティになります。グローバルオブジェクトとは、ブラウザでは`window`(最新のJavaScript環境では`globalThis`も使えます)です。つまり、トップレベルに書かれた`var AABB = "CC"`は`window["AABB"] = "CC"`とほぼ等しいと言うことです。ここまでわかればわかりますね。`window[tests1 + tests2]`を内部から順に評価していくと、`window["AA" + "BB"]`、`window["AABB"]`、`"CC"`となって、CCを表示できるようになるでしょう。

なお、このようにグローバルオブジェクトを通した方法はお勧めしません。モジュールとして読み込んだ場合や、Node.js等の環境(これらはトップレベルがグローバルコンテキストではない)では使えません。また、これは`var`だからできる方法であって、`let`や`const`では使えません。より汎用的に使えるようにするためにも、グローバルオブジェクトを通してアクセスするよりも、名前で値を取り出しするための`Object`または`Map`を用意する方法にすべきでしょう。例えば、次のようにです。

```js
const tests1 = "AA"
const tests2 = "BB"
const map = new Map([["AABB", "CC"]])

console.log(map.get(tests1 + tests2))
```

最後に、`eval`を使う方法もありますが、その危険性を自分の言葉で説明できない限り使うべきでは無い、と私は考えていますので、ここでは紹介しません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
evalについては質問をする前に考えてはいましたが、evalについて調べているとあまりよろしくないという記事をいくつか散見してこのような質問をしました。
たったこれだけの質問に対して、とてもご丁寧にご教授いただき、本当にありがとうございました。